# Add listener to a drop down menu

Tags: java, combobox, swt

So I have a drop down menu built below:

```
new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setText("Bet Type:");
betType = new Combo(shell, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
betType.setItems(new String[] {"   ", "NFL", "NBA", "CFB"});
betType.setLayoutData(gridData);
```

What I want is for when somebody selects one of the dropdown options, a function that I will write later will be called.

I've tried doing things like:

```
betType.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()) { ... }
```

Or:

```
betType.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener()) { ... }
```

Or:

```
betType.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener()) { ... }
```

And I keep getting errors saying "Cannot Instantiate the type ModifyListener or SelectionListener" etc. How would one go about correcting this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you close the first `(`-bracket too early.

This:

```
betType.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener()) { ... }
```

should be:

```
betType.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() { ... });
```

The following code does exactly what you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display d = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(d);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setText("Bet type:");

    final Combo betType = new Combo(shell, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
    betType.setItems(new String[] {"   ", "NFL", "NBA", "CFB"});

    betType.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            System.out.println(betType.getText());
        }
    });


    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
        while (!d.readAndDispatch())
            d.sleep();
}
```

Alternatively, this works as well:

```
betType.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0)
    {
        System.out.println(betType.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0)
    {
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah I just found the proper notation online, thank you for the clarification!